# Ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sheet_by_index'

Tags: python, openpyxl

Новичок в **Python**. Пишу бота в Telegram. Нужно отправить данные из ячейки *таблицы Excel*. Гуглил ошибку, понял, что она распространена, но как решить - примера нет.

*Python 3.5.1, openpyxl последняя, Windows 7 x64*

*Код:*

```
import os
import os.path

import openpyxl
import telebot

import constants

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(1)
    user_markup.row("1")
    user_markup.row("2")

if message.text == "test":
    rb = openpyxl.open_workbook('C:/Users/User/Desktop/table.xlsx', formatting_info=True)
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
    row = sheet.row_values(0)[0]
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, row)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/TestBot/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/TestBot/main.py", line 179, in <module>
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 174, in polling
self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site- packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 198, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 102, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 53, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/TestBot/main.py", line 155, in handle_text
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sheet_by_index'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: не могу ошибку воспроизвести. Вы должны получить `AttributeError: module 'openpyxl' has no attribute 'open_workbook'` с вашим кодом. Укажите версии python, openpyxl, Windows. Приведите полный traceback и код, который действительно используется.

Comment: @jfs всё добавил

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный traceback, а не только сообщение об ошибке

Comment: @soon спасибо, добвил

Comment: И еще укажите точную версию библиотеки (`openpyxl.__version__`).

Comment: Удивительно, что ошибка не вылетает в строке `rb = openpyxl.open_workbook('C:/Users/User/Desktop/table.xlsx', formatting_info=True)`, ведь в openpyxl нет функции `open_workbook()`. Есть `load_workbook()`, но у неё нет параметра `formatting_info`. Функция с такой сигнатурой есть в модуле xlrd.

Comment: @soon если не ошибаюсь, то это openpyxl 2.4.0-a1 (скачивал только вчера)

Comment: Проверьте еще отступы в коде - `if` должен находиться внутри функции, я полагаю

Comment: Также попробуйте убрать взаимодейтствие с ботом и просто открыть таблицу с помощью `openpyxl`, чтобы убедиться, что проблема именно в нем

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev @soon всё проверил, пробелы в порядке, проблема - в `openpyxl`. Думаю, именно в параметрах. Например, не `sheet_by_index`, а `get_index`. Такой параметр есть. А вот как дальше - не могу разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас код работы с документом не от [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html), а от [xlrd](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966). Для openpyxl должно быть так:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/User/Desktop/table.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
cell_val = sheet['A1'].value
```

Comment: Всё заработало! Спасибо!
Только вопрос такой: как отправлять сразу несколько значений?

Comment: Это не объясняет почему у автора строка с `rb = openpyxl.open_workbook()` не вылетает с `AttributeError`. Почему None возвращается.